# is $O(3^k)$ polynomial for $k\in o(n)$?

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics

For variable $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $O(3^n)$ is certainly an exponential, fix any integer $k\in o(n)$, is the function $O(3^k)$ polynomial ? If not when is it possible for $O(3^k)$ to become polynomial for $k$ depends on $n$.

Comment: If you *fix* $k$, then it isn't really $o(n)$, it is constant, i.e. $O(1)$.  If $k$ is a function of $n$, then you need to specify which function.

Answer (score 2):

$k$ has to be
$O(\log n)$
for
$3^k$
(or any $c^k$)
to be
$O(n^m)$
for some $m$.

Proof:
If 
$k = O(\log n)$,
then
$k < a \log n$,
so
$c^k
< c^{a \log n}
= e^{a \log c \log n}
= (e^{\log n})^{a \log c }
= n^{a \log c}
$
which is polynomial in $n$.

If
$\frac{k}{\log n}
\to \infty
$,
we can similarly show that
$c^k$
grows faster than
any $n^m$
for fixed $m$.

For example,
this happens for
$k = n^a$
for any $a > 0$
(such as
$k = \sqrt{n}$).

Comment: Thanks. In general though, $O(3^k)$ will remain polynomial as long as $k$ is a polynomial in $n$, correct?

Comment: No. As long as k is bounded by a constant times log n.